# How to change unique key to new field and update all the documents without re-indexing?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I want to change the unique key field of documents to a new field, and update documents without re-indexing. What are the options do we have to achieve this? Solr version 8.2 and using solr cloud.

Comment: If you change anything on the schema side...you need to reindex the data...there is not other alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change anything on the schema side, you need to reindex the data.
There is an alternative to it.

But the solr cloud has nice feature that can be used here without restarting the solr server.

1. Create a new config set.
2. Make all your changes in the newly created configSet.
3. Upload the newly created configset as zookeper maintains all your configsets.
4. Create a new collection using the new configset.
5. Index your data in new collection.
6. Once all the data is indexed, create an alias to new collection.
7. Give the alias name same as the old collection.
8. All your new request will be redirected to new collection.
9. Once everything is set you can delete the old collection.